# How to update JComboBox with method "addItem()" without Selected Item being changed

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I want to update JComboBox when I type in the JComboBox editor. It will get the text of JComboBox editor in real time and add some items based on the text. I have tried like this:

```java
final JTextField tfListText = (JTextField) comboBox1.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
tfListText.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    private String lastText;

    @Override
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        String text = tfListText.getText();
        if (!text.equals(lastText)) {
            lastText = text;
            comboBox1.removeAllItems();
            // get some items based on text
            comboBox1.addItem(someItems1);

            ...

        }
    }
});
```

However, the selected item of JComboBox was changed when using method `removeAllItems()` or `addItem()`, and it caused an endless loop triggering the CaretListener again.

So how to update JComboBox without selected item being changed, or is there any other way to add items based on the input content in real time

Comment: What would you expect to happen when you removeAllItems()? There are no items left to be selected.

Comment: @camickr Similar to the auto-completion. when you type, the completion options will be displayed in the drop-down box. So I expect to remove the old items and add some new ones

Comment: When I've done auto-completion, I've used a separate `JTextField` for the auto-completion input and a non-editable `JComboBox` for the results.  You could try that.

Comment: it's probably not entirely trivial - you need logic to a) disable the caretListener while updating the items and b) reset the selection to the lastValue after updating is done. Search for how others did autocompletion to get some concrete ideas (don't have a link at hand right now, sry)